# Calypsoify error generation after Jetpack 9.2 upgrade

Tags: wordpress, jetpack, wp-calypso

My site has had a significant issue after the automatic upgrade of Jetpack to version 9.2.  I'm unable to edit posts using the Jetpack plugin, but more importantly, multiple widgets have been turned off.

Bluehost support upgraded my site manually to PHP version 7.4 from 7.0, which had been recommended by another user as a potential fix, but it did not work.  I'm currently unable to use any Jetpack tools to edit my site, and have lost access to several widgets - in particular the Authors widget, which I use to allow site users to view the various authors who contribute to my site.

The error code generated from the site is as follows:

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 80 of the file /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/calypsoify/class.jetpack-calypsoify.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Class 'A8C_WPCOM_Masterbar' not found in /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/calypsoify/class.jetpack-calypsoify.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/calypsoify/class.jetpack-calypsoify.php(56): Jetpack_Calypsoify->mock_masterbar_activation()
#1 /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): Jetpack_Calypsoify->setup_admin('')
#2 /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(175): do_action('admin_init')
#5 /home3/theessk8/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(10): require_once('/home3/theessk8...')
#6 {main}
 thrown
```

And Bluehost determined the following source of the error:

legacy/class-jetpack-ixr-client.php  of hetpack plugin

Any help in curing this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for me too.

I've raised it with Jetpack, as have others...

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-will-not-work-after-jetpack-plugin-update/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to download JetPack 9.1 here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/advanced/

Install in Wordpress and downgrade the Jetpack version to 9.1